# mongodb Filtering / Projection

Tags: mongodb

Got mongo data looking like this. End goal is to filter and project data only having scores.groupScore and in the array, if only score is === 8. (This is obviously just an example. I have aa huge data set.)

```
_id:525252522
scores: {
  groupScore: [
    { name:"Norm", score: 7 },
    { name:"Mandy", score: 8 },
    { name:"Andy", score: 9 },
    { name:"Chris",score: 10 },
   ] 
 }
_id:98989898
scores: {
  groupScore: [
    { name:"tess", score: 7 },
    { name:"less", score: 8 },
    { name:"kess", score: 9 },
    { name:"yess",score: 10 },
   ] 
 }
```

Expected outcome

```
_id:525252522
scores: {
  groupScore: [
    { name:"Mandy", score: 8 }
   ] 
 }
_id:98989898
scores: {
  groupScore: [
    { name:"less", score: 8 }
   ] 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "scores.groupScore": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$scores.groupScore",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.score", 8 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```